# Binding a Panel to a Form

Tags: c#, winforms

I am making a Seabattle game where the Ships are hidden in a panel with a label array. This label array needs to have more or less rows and columns depending on the chosen difficulty level.

So I made a new class "Gameboard" where the Panel and the label array is defined.
The problem is that I cant figure out how to bind the panel I make in this class to the Form..

```
namespace SO_S2_Programmeren_Groep08 {
class GameBoard{

Panel pnlSlagveld;
private Label[,] lblArray;
private int row;
private int column;    

public Label[,] LblArray {
  get { 
    return lblArray; 
  }
  set { 
    lblArray = value; 
  }
}

public int Row {
  get { return row; }
  set { row = value; }
}

public int Column {
  get { return column; }
  set { column = value; }
}

public GameBoard(int row, int column) {
  this.row = row;
  this.column = column;
  CreateLableArray(row, column);
}

public GameBoard() {
  this.row = 7;
  this.column = 9;
  CreateLableArray(row, column);
}

private void CreateLableArray(int ingrow, int ingcolumn) {
  pnlBattleField = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
  lblArray = new Label[ingrow, ingcolumn];
  int xpos = 0;
  int ypos = 0;

  for (int row = 0; row < ingrow; row++) {

    for (int column = 0; column < ingcolumn; column++) {
      lblArray[row, column] = new Label();
      lblArray[row, column].Left = xpos;
      lblArray[row, column].Top = ypos;
      lblArray[row, column].Width = 50;
      lblArray[row, column].Height = 50;

      lblArray[row, column].Tag = (char)('A' + column) + (row + 1).ToString();
      lblArray[row, column].Click += lblArray_Click;
      lblArray[row, column].BackColor = Color.Aqua;
      lblArray[row, column].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;

      pnlBattlefield.Controls.Add(lblArray[row, column]);

      xpos += lblArray[row, column].Width;
    }
    ypos += lblArray[row, 0].Width;
    xpos = 0;
  }
}/*CreateLableArray*/

private void lblArray_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  MessageBox.Show("Clicked on Label " + ((Label)sender).Tag.ToString());
}

}
```

}

If you'd like to see more classes please ask!

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please show me the line of code that adds the panel to a form? I'm not used to working with Windows Forms Application :/

Comment: `Form someform = ...;  someForm.Controls.Add(somePanel);` But you probably don't want to do that, you want to restructure your program a tiny bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do one of these:

1. Make 'GameBoard' a form, and then add the panel to that form.  If you wanted to do this I would suggest creating a windows forms project (if you haven't already) and adding this code to the code for the main form (or a new form that you add) so that you have the designer components and all of the visual studio features of a form.
2. Make it a usercontrol and add that usercontrol to a form.  If you wanted to do this, I would add a new user control to the project and add this code to that usercontrol, again, so you get visual studio support.
3. Create a `new Form()` inside of your gameboard and add it to that.  (That's contrary to standard form practices in winforms, and you won't get as much IDE help, so I wouldn't suggest this for a new programmer).

Comment: Thanks!
The reason I i'd like the panel to be defined in another class is that the Form.cs already has alot of code (the ships have to be placed by random on the labelarray)

So maybe it's better to move that code to another class instead of the the "GameBoard"

Comment: @David That's why I have point #2, which it sounds like is the best fit for you.  This can be considered a complex "component" which is separate from the rest of the form, and can be added to that form.  You could of course just go into the form control and do a `Controls.Add(somePanel)` as well, sure.

Comment: Thanks alot!
I think I got it figured out.. and tought this was going to be the easy part :)

Comment: I added this to my Form.Designer.cs:

    Gameboard board = new Gameboard();
    board.Controls.Add(board.PnlGameboard);

Comment: Everytime I change to anther level, the previous panel sits on top of the newly created panel :/
Do you guys have a suggestion to the "null" the previus panel?
Thanks!

Comment: I'll pre-phrase that..How to remove a previous made panel? Thanks!

Comment: Well, the easiest option would probably be to just change the contents of the panel rather than removing it and adding a new one.  You can also find it through the 'Controls' collection of whatever you added it to.  If it's the only control you added it'll be easy to find, if not you can use the `Find` method or some other search criteria.